# Intercepting Requests Using Spring Security Rather Than putting pre-handler Interceptor

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, interceptor

I am building a Spring MVC web-application. I want to intercept the request with some business logic of validating token stored in database. I want some alternative to HandlerInterceptor's preHandle method. I am trying to implement the same with Spring Security.Please suggest some way.

---

**EDIT**

This is how I intercept all requests in my web application :

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
      Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestInterceptor.class);

      @Override
      public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

           //I validate user's token from my database here
           //return true if valid token else false

        }
}
```

My servlet-context.xml looks like

```
 <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.clarice.rest.security.RequestInterceptor">
        <property name="XXX">
            <list>
                <value>YYY</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

So my question is , Is there any way to implement the same interceptor kind of thing using Spring Security writing my own code as I do in RequestInterceptor class ?

Comment: You should show, or at least mention something you have tried already. If you haven't read the Spring Security documentation you should start there. You may want to start with the "[Filters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#security-filter-chain)" section.

Comment: Please look at the edited part, hope it helps you.And please provide some inputs

Comment: please give some suggestions I am still stuck into this part